# Parsing through django queryset output without duplication

Tags: django, django-models

I have 3 tables students,colleges and courses and i have done a join query which returns each student and his college and the courses he registered. In the output for each student there are multiple records as he registered for multiple courses where the student details and colleage details are same. I'm executing a raw sql in this case. I need to display this on a template in the below format.

**Student Name, College**
 - Course1
 - Course2
 - Course3

Here is the query,

```
cursor=connection.cursor()
result=cursor.execute('''SELECT
s.student_id,
s.student_Name,
c.college_id,
c.college_name,
cs.course_id,
cs.course_name,
FROM student s
INNER JOIN college c on s.student_id=c.college_id
INNER JOIN course cs on s.student_id=cs.course_id''')
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer myself,

```
cursor=connection.cursor()
result=cursor.execute('''SELECT
s.student_id,
s.student_Name,
c.college_id,
c.college_name,
array_agg(cs.course_id),
array_agg(cs.course_name),
FROM student s
INNER JOIN college c on s.student_id=c.college_id
INNER JOIN course cs on s.student_id=cs.course_id
GROUP BY s.student_id,s.student_Name,c.college_id,c.college_name''')
```

array_agg can be used as an equivalent for MySQL GROUP_CONTACT (Not really, but it works)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL you can use GROUP_CONTACT but you should actually use Django'S ORM for this. In the template it should look something like:

```
{% for student in students %}
<tr>
  <td> {{ student }} </td>
  <td> {{ student.colleges | join:', ' }} </td>
  <td> {{ student.course | join:', ' }} </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Of course you can use select_related to lower the number of SQL queries made.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, i would really appreciate if you can help me to write a manager method to retrieve the output of this query.